Apache CSV Parser read column by column
I have a csv file like the below one and need to parse the file using Apache commons CSV Parser , not record by record but column by column




Column A
Column B




Cell 1
Cell 2


Cell 3
Cell 4




The desired result I want to read like is

Column A , Cell 1 ,Cell 3


Column B  , Cell 2, Cell 4

Is there anyway that CSV Parser allows to read like this . I foreseen in the documentation that it only reads record by record.

That's right - it only reads records by record.
So how to get what you want? Many ways to do this, e.g.

if you are confident the data will easily fit in memory, and if the data is "square" then you could create 2 dimension array structure like this: String[][] data = new String[colCount][rowCount];, transcribe the data into the array in one "direction" and read it out in the other
if your data is very large, consider using an external storage option, like a database or MapDB


The main problem I am facing is that the data is quite large and I cannot afford to store it in a map or DB. I wanted to know if there are any options that would lead to read the CSV File column by column sequentially.

I very much doubt it... think about how the data is read from the file... it reads row by row, so there is no magic here, except to read line by line, split out the data as you go into columns, accumulate them and then play out the data in column form - which you cannot do until you read the last byte of the CSV source.

The physical file tas no concept of columns. The file is just a sequence of octets.
In that sequence of octets, the content of the second field follows the first, and the content of each “row” follows the one before. This means entire rows must be read in sequence.
So, read your rows in Apache Commons CSV. For each row, add each field to its respective collection you setup to represent each “column”.
ArrayList < String > columnA = new ArrayList<>() ;
ArrayList < String > columnB = new ArrayList<>() ;

Read each row. Add the first field value to the first list. Add the second field value to the second list. Repeat.
